# How to add background images to front page of Pages doc?

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

Want to add background images to the front page only of a Pages doc.

I can't understand how to do this—reading the Apple doc on this didn't help unfortunately. Can't get background images (Master Objects?) working at all.

Using Pages 6.2.

Also noting that Arrange > Section Masters > Move Object to Section Master is greyed out...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Make the front page its own section. From the Document Setup inspector, choose
   Section → Create a new section.
2. Add your image to the front page and position it how you desire.
3. With the image still selected, choose
   Arrange → Section Masters → Move Object to Section Master